# Add Thousand Separator & 2 decimals to ngModel Input

Tags: angular

I've been trying to add a thousand separators & 2 decimals to my input values as below

**TS**

```
  onBlur(event){
    if (event.target.value !== ''){
      event.target.value = (parseFloat(event.target.value).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString();
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0.00" [(ngModel)]="grade.secondTerm " [disabled]="grade.disable" (keypress)="NumberOnly($event)" (blur)="onBlur($event)">
```

this only shows 2 decimals. How can I get them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Intl.Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) format

```
onBlur(event){
    if (event.target.value !== ''){
      event.target.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(event.target.value)
    }
  }
```